# Question on the uniqueness of LU decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Let $A \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times n}$ a matrix, and suppose that we can run the [Gaussian elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) on $A$ without row or column interchange, so there exist the [$LU$ decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) of $A$.

We define the $LU$ decomposition as $U \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times n}$ is an upper triangle matrix, and $L \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times n}$ is a lower triangle matrix, with $\ell_{i,i}=1$ main diagonal elements, and $A=LU$.

We know, that if $\det(A) \neq 0$, so $A$ is invertible, then the $LU$ decomposition is unique. Quite easy to show that by contradiction.

**Questions.**

$(1)$ Is there any other condition for the uniqueness of $LU$ decomposition, even if $\det(A)=0$?

$(2)$ Is there a necessary and sufficient condition for uniqueness of $LU$ decomposition?

Comment: If the leading $k\times k$ submatrices of $A$ (i.e. the top left $k\times k$ submatrices) are all invertible for $k=1,\cdots,n-1$, then an LU factorisation exists and is unique. Conversely if one of them is singular, the LU factorisation of $A$ is either nonexistent or not unique. Unfortunately, I can only prove it one way (not the converse).

Comment: @Sarastro Actually, the nonsingularity of leading principal submatrices is also necessary for the existence. If one of them is singular, the LU factorization simply does not exist since we get a zero pivot.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Please take a look at my [question here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1247300/153012).

Comment: @Algebraic Pavel what about the zero matrix? I dont think it has a non zero principa minor, however infinite LU exist