# Really confused about LU decomposition and Doolittle algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I'm really confused about the [Doolittle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Doolittle_algorithm), so I need some help.

At the end of the description at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Doolittle_algorithm), it says

> It is clear that in order for this algorithm to work, one needs to
>   have $a_{n,n}^{(n-1)}\not=0$ at each step (see the definition of
>   $l_{i,n}$).

And also all the book says this, so I think I'm wrong somewhere, but take a look at the following example:

$$A:= \left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 1&2/3&1/2&2/5\\ 3/2&1&3
/4&3/5\\ 2&4/3&1&4/5\\ 5/2&5/3&5/4
&1\end {array} \right]. 
$$

In $A$ each column and each row has linear dependence, so for example we can get each row with a constant multiplication of the first row. To make it clear, if we denote the $i$-th row with $r_i$, then $r_2=(3/2)r_1$, $r_3=2r_1$ and $r_4=(5/2)r_1$.

So let's try to run the Doolittle algorithm! $A^{(0)}:=A$, $a_{1,1}^{(0)} = 1\neq 0$. It' ok. Now compute $L_1$.
$$
L_1 =  
\left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 1&0&0&0\\ -a_{2,1}^{(0)}/a_{1,1}^{(0)}&1&0&0
\\ -a_{3,1}^{(0)}/a_{1,1}^{(0)}&0&1&0\\ -a_{4,1}^{(0)}/a_{1,1}^{(0)}&0&0&1
\end {array} \right] =
\left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 1&0&0&0\\ -3/2&1&0&0
\\ -2&0&1&0\\ -5/2&0&0&1
\end {array} \right]. 
$$
Now if we take a step in the iteration, we get
\begin{align}
A^{(1)}=L_1 A^{(0)} &=
\left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 1&0&0&0\\ -3/2&1&0&0
\\ -2&0&1&0\\ -5/2&0&0&1
\end {array} \right] \cdot
\left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 1&2/3&1/2&2/5\\ 3/2&1&3
/4&3/5\\ 2&4/3&1&4/5\\ 5/2&5/3&5/4
&1\end {array} \right] \\ \\ &= 
 \left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 1&2/3&1/2&2/5\\ 0&0&0&0
\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\end {array}
 \right]. 
\end{align}
And here the Doolittle algorithm stops, because $a_{2,2}^{(1)} = 0$, and that's why we couldn't compute $L_2$.

And there are theorems about it, that $a_{n,n}^{(n-1)}$ must be nonzero $n=1,\dots,N-1$ (where $A$ is an $N \times N$ matrix) or equivalently all the principal subminors have to be nonzero from $n=1,\dots,N-1$. You can find a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1246733/153012).

We obtain that all these statements are false in our $4 \times 4$ size $A$ matrix.

But why we need to run $n$ from $1$ to $N-1$, if get an upper triangle matrix $A^{(\ell)}$ for an $\ell < N-1$ ?

Because we've got an upper triangle matrix for $A^{(1)}$, and as we see
$$
L_1^{-1} =  \left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 1&0&0&0\\3/2&1&0&0
\\ 2&0&1&0\\ 5/2&0&0&1\end {array}
 \right]
$$
is a lower triangle matrix.

So it seems to me with $L:=L_1^{-1}$, and $U:=A^{(1)}$, we've got an $LU$ decomposition of $A$.

*Questions.*

1. Am I wrong somewhere?
2. If I'm right, then is there a modified Doolittle algorithm, which do the job for the example given above? I'm really need a citation too.
3. Is this true, that in the example $L$ and $U$ gives a unique $LU$ decomposition of $A$, if we restrict that the diagonal of $L$ in the decomposition contains only ones? If it is or not, why?

Comment: You should notice that discussions about nonzero pivots, existence of LU etc. in most books and on wiki assum explicitly that $A$ is nonsingular so they do not extent trivially to the singular case.